Sign of the solution operator applied to the positive part
For a given $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, by Riesz Representation Theorem there exists a unique $u_f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that weak solution of
$$
-\Delta u + u = f, \quad \mathbb{R}^N,
$$
that is
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u_f \nabla \varphi + u_f \varphi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f \varphi, \quad \forall \varphi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N).
$$
Is it true that $u_{f^+}(x) = 0$ for all $ x \in \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N : f(x) < 0\}$? If this is not the case, whould this be true assuming $f \in W^{2,p}_{\textrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ ?

If the claim would be true, then it would imply that $u_f(x)$ and $f(x)$ have the same sign almost everywhere. This is not the case.
Take
$$
u(x) = \chi_{ (0,2\pi) } ( 1- \cos(nx))
$$
with $n\in \mathbb N$ large. Then $u \in H^1(\mathbb R)$.
Now set
$$
f(x) = -u''(x) + u(x).
$$
And $f$ and $u$ do not have the same sign a.e.

This has noting to do with smoothness of $f$. Take $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)\setminus\{0\}$ with $\phi \ge0$. Then its second derivative cannot be
non-positive. Define $u(x) := \phi(nx)$. And for $n$ large enough $-u''+u$ will change sign while $\phi$ will not change sign.

I have a doubt. By the same reason that $\phi''$ can not be non-positive, we can conclude that $\phi''$ can not be non-negative, right?
